# text format trouble objective-c

Tags: objective-c, text, label, text-formatting

need to make effect, that text is interrupted by another text/uiimageview, but cannot understand how does it works. For example i need to make interface similar to ios7 status bar where operator name such a "Oper ..." + icon + time. So i cannot do this right way

```
operatorName = [self getOperatorName];
    UILabel *operatorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    operatorLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    operatorLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:kStatusBarFontOperatorSize];
    operatorLabel.textColor = kStatusBarTextColor;
    operatorLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.f, -0.6);
    operatorLabel.shadowColor = kStatusBarTextShadow;
    operatorLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    operatorLabel.text = operatorName;

    operatorLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, operatorStrSize.width, operatorStrSize.height);
    [operatorLabel sizeToFit];


    /* connection type */
    UIImageView *conImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:conImg];


    /* time in status bar */
    time = [self getStatusBarTime];
    UILabel *statusBarLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    statusBarLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:kStatusBarFontSize];
    statusBarLabel.textColor = kStatusBarTextColor;

    statusBarLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    statusBarLabel.text = time;


    int maxDistance = imgView.frame.size.width/2 - timeStrSize.width/2;

    int connectionPower = 44;
    double delimiter = 0;
    NSString *cName = [self returnChoosenConnectionName];
    if ([cName isEqualToString:@"Wi-Fi"]) {
        delimiter = 6.5;
    } else {
        delimiter = 9.5;
    }
    int fullLine = connectionPower + operatorLabel.frame.size.width + delimiter + conImgView.frame.size.width;


    if (fullLine > maxDistance) {

        // need to interrupt  text in operator name, but how ?

    } else {

        // all good placed
        x = 44.0;
        operatorLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, 3.0, operatorStrSize.width  , operatorStrSize.height);
        [operatorLabel sizeToFit];


        NSString *cName = [self returnChoosenConnectionName];
        if ([cName isEqualToString:@"Wi-Fi"]) {
            x += operatorLabel.frame.size.width + 6.5;
        } else {
            x += operatorLabel.frame.size.width + 9.5;
        }

        conImgView.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0.0, conImgView.frame.size.width, conImgView.frame.size.height);

        [imgView addSubview:operatorLabel];
        [imgView addSubview:conImgView];
    }

    statusBarLabel.frame = CGRectMake(imgView.frame.size.width/2 - timeStrSize.width/2, 2.5, timeStrSize.width , timeStrSize.height);
    [imgView addSubview:statusBarLabel];
```

What i need:
[image: how must to be]

what i have:
[image: what i have]

Comment: I'd suggest you to use autolayout rather than doing the layout yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use xib for this and also autolayout

Comment: xib is not required. You may create and set constraints programatically.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use autolayout rather than trying to calculate everything yourself. You may use XIB and set constraints in there or you may do everything programmatically. Here is a sample code that will get you started. It creates controls and sets constraints programatically; it doesn't use XIB.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /*
     Uncomment this if you would like to translate your subviews vertically.

     UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
     [self.view addSubview:view];
     UIView *superview = view;
     */

    UIView *superview = self.view;

    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0];
    label1.text = @"MTS";
    [label1 sizeToFit];
    [label1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:14.0];
    label2.text = @"1:22 PM";
    [label2 sizeToFit];
    [label2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strength.png"]];
    UIImageView *image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"carrier.png"]];
    [image1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [image2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [image1 sizeToFit];
    [image2 sizeToFit];

    [superview addSubview:image1];
    [superview addSubview:label1];
    [superview addSubview:image2];
    [superview addSubview:label2];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(image1, image2, label1, label2);
    NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"|-[image1(<=%f)]-[label1]-[image2(<=%f)]-[label2(>=20)]-|",
                        image1.frame.size.width, image2.frame.size.width];
    NSArray *constraints;
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format
                                                          options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

When adding views to a layout in code iOS will attempt to convert the autosizing mask for that view to auto layout constraints. Those auto-generated constraints will conflict with any constraints added within the application code. It is essential to turn the translation off:

```
setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO
```

The result of the code is:

[image]

Comment: Big thanks for yout answer ! good variant, but i already wrote my alghoritm to count distance between elements, so it good works for every position and also when need to crop operator label, it's maybe not good practice, but works like a shine )